# trigger fire when SAL col is updated with new salary hike. Also Trigger will update 20% of salary hike amount in X col in EMPL table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

Write a trigger which will fire when SAL column is updated with new salary hike. Also Trigger will update 20% of salary hike amount in  C_M column in “EMPL” table.

```
AFTER UPDATE OF SAL
ON EMPLOYE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.sal >old.sal)
DECLARE
SAL_DIFF employe.sal%type;
BEGIN
UPDATE EMPLOYE SET COMM=(SAL_DIFF*20)/100
WHERE SAL_DIFF=:NEW.SAL-:OLD.SAL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended');
WHEN others THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like that.

Your trigger is *anything but* as

- you can't reference new or old values in an `after` trigger as you'd get "ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type" error
- don't `update` table which is just being modified by the same transaction; you'd get a mutating table error.
- `where` clause is completely wrong; if it were a "normal" `update` statement (out of the trigger), you'd have to use e.g. primary key column in the `where` clause, not *that*
- `exception` handling section is probably the strangest I've ever seen. Besides, it is completely useless and misleading. There's nothing that is capable of raising `no_data_found`, while `others` can't happen either. What do you think could raise it?

Consider something like this instead:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_sal
  2    before update of sal on employee
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.sal > old.sal)
  5  begin
  6    :new.comm := (:new.sal - :old.sal) * 20 / 100;
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from employee;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7839 KING             5000
      7934 MILLER           1300
```

This `update` will modify King's salary. It'll also fire the trigger which will update King's `comm` column value.

```
SQL> update employee set sal = 6000 where ename = 'KING';

1 row updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from employee;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7839 KING             6000        200           --> this
      7934 MILLER           1300

SQL>
```